# Python with neo4j 2.x

Tags: python, neo4j

Are there any python libraries that are meant to work with neo4j 2.x?

I would like to use an ORM (OGM?) with python, but all the ones I have tried don't support labels, they create a node and relationship to the object type.

Are there any packages currently (or in the works) that will support the 2.x style labels? Or am I missing some functionality in the current ORM packages? (neo4django, neomodel, neo4py)

Django support would be a plus, but not a requirement.

Edit:

I have had success with neo4jrestclient as a way to manipulate nodes/relationships/labels, but I am looking for a way to set up types of nodes easily with specific fields and properties/rules for combining those nodes in specific ways.

Comment: AFAIK Py2neo works with 2.x, but it's not an OGM. Have a look! https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo

Comment: It says [here](http://pythonhosted.org//py2neo/) that, "Note: Some preparation has been made for support of node labels, available in Neo4j 2.0. However, no features have yet been implemented in py2neo to make any label functionality available to client applications." So I haven't tried that one.

Comment: Oh ok. I think you could still use labels via Cypher queries as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neomodel has a neo4j 2.x development branch (https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel/tree/feature_neo4j_2_0). It is very much a work in progress at this point and I had to tweak some of the code to get it to properly handle relationships in neo4j 2.1.2 but even in its current state I find it easier to use than the OGM provided by py2neo.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at that. Thanks for the heads up. I didn't realize that branch was in development.